# How to execute a system command and display its state in the Text Widget table

Tags: perl, perltk

I tried to achieve above using the snippet from CPAN `Tk::ExecuteCommand` module but it gives me errors below when I execute any Perl program within the `$ec->configure(-command` section.

Also, the window will be closed unexpectedly once the Perl job completed.  The script works and will not be closed if I just print the text instead of command within the entry (as the line I commented out).  I choose to use this Cpan program as I wanted 2 things:

1. To show the system command and run result within the text widget.
2. To have the "execute button" turn to "cancel" when a job is running so that user could have chances to cancel an ongoing job.
   May I know how to achieve that?

Here is the error msg I get:

```
 > /usr/bin/perl: symbol lookup error: /usr/pkgs/perl/5.14.1/lib64/module/default/x86_64-linux/auto/Proc/ProcessTable/ProcessTable.so: undefined symbol: pthread_once
```

[13]   Exit 127                      test1.pl

And here is the code I used:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Tk;
use Tk::ExecuteCommand;

$ec = tkinit()->ExecuteCommand(
     -command    => '',
     -entryWidth => 50,
     -height     => 10,
     -label      => '',
     -text       => 'Execute',
)->pack;
$ec->configure(-command => 'perl ./my_script.pl -wrapper wrapper_txt');
#$ec->configure(-command => 'Text line only');
$ec->execute_command;
$ec->update;

MainLoop;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `$ec->configure(-command => 'perl ./my_script.pl -wrapper wrapper_txt');` to `$ec->configure(-command => 'perl my_script.pl -wrapper wrapper_txt');`

and to get the status use a sub like below

```
sub sys {

    # Execute a command asynchronously and return its status and output.

    my $cmd = shift;

    $ec->configure( -command => $cmd );
    my $t = $ec->Subwidget( 'text' ); # ROText widget
    $t->delete( '1.0' => 'end' );
    $ec->execute_command;
    return ($ec->get_status)[0], split /\n/, $t->get( '1.0' => 'end -1 chars' );

} # end sys
```

For killing it using a button, check the documentation, it says

> This ExecuteCommand mega widget is composed of an LabEntry widget for
>   command entry, a "Do It" Button that initiates command execution, and
>   a ROText widget that collects command execution output. While the
>   command is executing, the "Do It" Button changes to a "Cancel" Button
>   that can prematurely kill the executing command. The kill_command
>   method does the same thing programmatically.

So you need `$exec->execute_command;` `$exec->get_status;` and `$exec->kill_command;`.

Edit: Looks like a [**known issue**](http://blogs.perl.org/users/gabor_szabo/2012/09/procprocesstable-needs-a-c-lover.html), try using latest version of Proc::ProcessTable.

Also see: [**Bug #41397 for Proc-ProcessTable: Proc::ProcessTable - make test fails "undefined symbol: pthread_once"**](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=41397)

Comment: hi Chankey, Thanks for your reply.  WIth the code I posted above, they actually works but it abort once the perl command run complete ( I saw the result prompt within the text widget, but the window closed immediately after that). At the Unix prompt which I invoked the script, it shows error " symbol lookup error: /usr/pkgs/perl/5.14.1/lib64/module/default/x86_64-linux/auto/Proc/ProcessTable/ProcessTable.so: undefined symbol: pthread_once".  The suggested solution seems not works for me :(.

Comment: Then it looks like some libraries are missing. Are you using latest version of `Proc::ProcessTable`? See this: http://blogs.perl.org/users/gabor_szabo/2012/09/procprocesstable-needs-a-c-lover.html

Comment: I'm actually not sure how to check that and I suppose that should be included when I called the "use Tk::ExecuteCommand" right?. My Perl version is v5.14.1.

Comment: `perl -MProc::ProcessTable -e 'print $MODULE::VERSION';` The latest version is 0.50 https://metacpan.org/pod/Proc::ProcessTable

Comment: I have included "use Proc::ProcessTable;" but seems still complaining same error. Could you explain what is this error means?  Wonder if above codes works at your end?

Comment: You don't have to include Proc::ProcessTable. Just check the version of it using the above command I wrote. There were many bugs in 0.45 version of module, I suspect you are using that version. Check it. `perl -MProc::ProcessTable -e 'print $MODULE::VERSION';`

Comment: I failed to check the version with either of these:- (i)system ("perl -MProc::ProcessTable -e 'print $MODULE::VERSION'")  ; (ii) `perl -MProc::ProcessTable -e 'print $MODULE::VERSION';` ;

Comment: do `cpan Proc::ProcessTable` from your shell.

Comment: Like this? > cpan Proc::ProcessTable
CPAN: File::HomeDir loaded ok (v0.66)

Comment: `[root@host]# cpan Proc::ProcessTable`. Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/dEDVHPU.jpg

Comment: The only I get is : > cpan Proc::ProcessTable
CPAN: File::HomeDir loaded ok (v0.66)
CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.18)
CPAN: LWP::UserAgent loaded ok (v5.816)
CPAN: Time::HiRes loaded ok (v1.9711)

Comment: What's the output of this: `perldoc -l Proc::ProcessTable`

Comment: > perldoc -l Proc::ProcessTable 
/usr/pkgs/perl/5.14.1/lib64/module/r1/x86_64-linux/Proc/ProcessTable.pm

Comment: It's installed then. Try running your script again, do you get same error?

Comment: See the edited answer, it's a bug. In the link you'll find the patch to solve this.

Comment: Could you pls pin point me the error?  I could spot where is it within the  link.  And the http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/SREZIC/patches/Proc-ProcessTable-0.45-MSCHILLI-02.patch is unaccessible to me though.

Comment: Download the module from here: https://metacpan.org/pod/Proc::ProcessTable and install it manually. Link to patch for 0.45 version is: http://www.cpan.org/modules/by-module/Geo/SREZIC/patches/Proc-ProcessTable-0.45-MSCHILLI-02.patch

Comment: I have downloaded and untar, may I know how to apply it on my script?  Can you give me a sample?  Thanks in advanced.

Comment: I declared as below, yet still getting same error msg:-
use Tk;                                                                    use Tk::ExecuteCommand;
use lib '/nfs/fm/grace_work/Proc-ProcessTable-0.50' ;

Comment: Then I guess the bug is not solved in 0.50 also. Can't do anything about it.

Comment: DO you have alternative solution to achieve that beside using this cpan method?

Comment: Hi Pathak, I'm finally able to apply the execute cpan module by changing my perl shebang to newer version.  Thanks for the hint. I actually still not able to achieve my goal as my codes reading from wrapper instead of a command line. I'm wondering if I can really apply this execute command module. I'm going to create a new question on this forum.  Pls see if you could help me on that too.  Thanks!